# Qt Database issue with scope_identity()

Tags: sql-server, database, qt, driver, qtsql

I am trying to debug the scope_Identity() call in qt. To elaborate on that scope_identity supposed to return the sessions last inserted data ID, but this call does not work accordingly in Qt database calls. I am trying to figure if this returns a value from the database driver to Qt codes at all and at this point I manage to track the code executions to

```
bool QODBCResult::reset (const QString& query)
```

method in qsql_odbc.cpp class.

In this method it accesses some win32 __stdcall calls, one of which I believe is responsible in connecting and retrieving data from the database.

```
SQLSetStmtAttr
SQLAllocHandle
SQLExecDirect
```

I am unable to find the code for these and I appreciate if someone can guide me on this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to ask your favorite search engine? Perhaps it would guide you to the MSDN documentation pages (e.g. for [SQLExecDirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms713611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) or to this question on stackoverflow: [scope_identity vs ident_current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567171/scope-identity-vs-ident-current) that may contain an answer to your troubles.