# IDENT_CURRENT returns the last identity value but SCOPE_IDENTITY does not

Tags: sql-server, scope-identity

I have a SQL Server as backend for an asp.net application. Multiple people might insert data in the same table 'the same time...'.

When I read the solution/answer from this post: [scope_identity vs ident_current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567171/scope-identity-vs-ident-current)

THEN I should not use the `Ident_current` because I could get the id of the insert of another user.

But using `Select Scope_Identity();` returns me NULL while the `Select IDENT_CURRENT('tableName')` returns me the correct id which I checked with SQL Server Management Studio.

The insert statement I do within a `SqlTransaction`. The `Select IDENT_CURRENT('tableName')` is done after the transaction.

What do I wrong?

**UPDATE**:

My insert statement which is dynamically build together by a base class:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (NAME) VALUES (@Name)
```

The command's Parameter collection has the value "xxx" and everything is fine inserted into the table.

I do NOT use stored procedures just pure `SqlDataReader` with C#.

```
commandText = "INSERT INTO TEST (NAME) VALUES ('Test1');Select Scopy_Identity();"
```

How can I get the last auto inc id running the above statement and should I call `ExecuteNonQuery` or `ExecuteReader` for the above because it has a `INSERT` and `SELECT` that's confusing...

Comment: Show us your insert command. Have a look at my answer on a similar question last week, maybe it's helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319532/return-value-from-sql-server-insert-command-using-c-sharp/9319609#9319609 You must use scope_identity in the same scope.

Comment: You probably executed the two commands completely independently.

Comment: I execute them independently.

Comment: Then `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` won't work - they must be in the same scope (hence the name). Use a stored procedure that sends the generated ID back as an output parameter, then you can keep it in session or wherever so you can reference it later.

Comment: @Pascal then how do you expect **SCOPE** identity to pull the identity from a different scope?  It's called **SCOPE** identity for a very clear reason...

Comment: You use a SQLDatareader to insert rows into a table? And you're not using stored procedures because...?

Comment: @Aaron nah the SqlDataReader is for fetching data...

Comment: Why do you keep undoing my edits? I'm making your question more readable. Please use the code button `{}` to mark lines of code.

Comment: I did not know that you edited my question ??? Maybe therefore?...

Comment: Problem solved: _cmd.CommandText = string.Concat(_cmd.CommandText + ";Select Scope_Identity();");
                lastId= Convert.ToInt32(_cmd.ExecuteScalar()); Someone can put this in a solutio if he wants :P

Comment: @Pascal - You can add it as an answer yourself, there's nothing wrong with that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use the [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) and you can insert the data and select back all (even multiple) identities in the same statement:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (NAME) OUTPUT INSERTED.YourIdentity VALUES (@Name)
```

working example:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (YourIdentity int identity(1,1) primary key, YourCol1 varchar(5))

INSERT INTO @YourTable (YourCol1) OUTPUT INSERTED.YourIdentity VALUES ('ABC')
```

OUTPUT:

```
YourIdentity
------------
1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: There is no need to read the last row id in a variable if its not reused. Your scenario makes more sense in a Store Procedure I think. But it works the same as Scope_Identiy so I mark it as solution although I do not use it ;-)

Comment: my example does not put the identity into a variable!  the "working example" code creates a variable table, so there is a place to insert a row and generate an identity.  The `OUTPUT INSERTED.YourIdentity` causes the insert statement to generate a result set that contains the identity value that was inserted.  this solution uses a single INSERT to both insert the data and select out identity value.  Your solution in the comments, uses two commands to achieve the same thing.  if you use OUTPUT in your insert, you can eliminate the `;Select Scopy_Identity();` code.

Comment: Note that this will give an error if the table has an insert trigger. Then you need to use `OUTPUT INTO` instead of just `OUTPUT`

Answer (score 20):

`IDENT_CURRENT` returns the last identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

`@@IDENTITY` returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session, across all scopes.

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session and the current scope.