# Get latest identity, such as ID, from an empty table SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have noticed that SQL keeps track of the latest identity (field it automatically increments each time a new record is created). I want to retrieve the latest identity from the table using C#. Unfortunately most of the time the table is empty (records are written and removed after a while, so often the table is empty).
Is this possible to do this within the bounds of the C# SQL API or do I have to create a stored procedure to retrieve this?

[image]

To better explain. If the row above was removed, the next ID number for the next record would be 32. I want to retrieve 32 before the record is written in, in the situation where the table is empty.

Comment: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1` ?

Comment: What happens if there are two calls for the next ID, then the next ID assigned might not be what you expect when you go to write your record.

Comment: Lots of good info in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567171/scope-identity-vs-ident-current

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table_name')+1;
```

---

> IDENT_CURRENT returns the last identity value generated for a specific
>   table in any session and any scope.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx

---

However, although this shows what the next ID will be, this doesn't always mean it will be the next ID entered by yourself. Someone else could `INSERT` a new record before you.

In short, there is no way of returning the value of what you will next be inserting.

Comment: +1 because it answers the question, but you may want to note that the number it returns may not be the ID of the next row that *you* would insert (because someone else inserted ahead of you).

Answer (score 0):

That would be the following query

> DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[TableName]', NORESEED )

Comment: You should include the NORESEED parameter; otherwise this will also potentially reseed the identity value (in the event that the current identity and the max identity value are different).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the increment is not the regular "1":

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('mytable') + IDENT_INCR('mytable')
```

Of course, all these rely on the identity column having been populated consistently, ie no messing with manual inserts or reseeding. And Curt has mentioned the possible concurrency issue if you're going to use this ID for your insert directly.