# Syntax issue in my SQL Server Stored Procedure with a BIT value type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert an xmlString value and bit value of 1 into the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sbssp_ArchivedMessages]
(
      @xmlString varchar(max),
      @fromToMach bit
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @idoc int, @lastId int
      EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xmlString, @fromToMach

      INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages]
      SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/Mach', 2) WITH [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages]

      SET @lastId = (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tblArchivedMessages'))

      UPDATE [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages] 
        SET FromToMach = @fromToMach 
        WHERE ID = @lastId
END
```

When I execute the SP I am doing so as follows:

```
EXEC dbo.sbssp_InsertArchivedMessages '<MACH><B000>StringVal</B000><B002>StringVal</B002><B003>StringVal</B003><B004>StringVal</B004><B007>StringVal</B007><B011>StringVal</B011><B012>StringVal</B012><B013>StringVal</B013><B015>StringVal</B015><B018>StringVal</B018><B028>StringVal</B028><B032>StringVal</B032><B037>StringVal</B037><B039>StringVal</B039><B041>StringVal</B041><B043>StringVal</B043><B048>StringVal</B048><B049>StringVal</B049><B058>StringVal</B058><B061>StringVal</B061><B063>StringVal</B063><B127>StringVal</B127></MACH>', 1
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> *Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sbssp_InsertArchivedMessages,
>   Line 13
>
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'FromToMach', table
>   'MachoPOSt.dbo.ArchivedMessages'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails. The statement has been terminated.*

Any suggestions on what exactly I'm doing wrong?  I've also put the @variable names in front of each value but still get the same error.

Any help/direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have not null column - `FromToATM`, make sue you insert value for that column.

Comment: And your row pattern should be `/MACH` not `/ATM`  based on string value you are passing to procedure, if you use `/ATM` then there is no match and it will return 0 rows

Comment: Mr. Fuzzy... I've got 131 columns.

Comment: You should use [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) instead of [IDENT_CURRENT(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx). See also  this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567171/scope-identity-vs-ident-current).

Comment: Thanks for the additional info on SCOPE_IDENTITY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not populating one of the columns

I am not sure what the table looks like but the problem is this

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages]
      SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/ATM', 2) WITH [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages]
```

The problem is the value that you pass into the FromToATM column

Comment: I'm confused. When I execute the SP I am entering a numeric value of 1 at the end of the string as indicated above. I am passing in a value for fromToMach, is that not correct?  Here is it again:

EXEC dbo.sbssp_InsertArchivedMessages '<MACH><B000>StringVal</B000>...', 1

Comment: You are correct, I misread the column name, the problem is the insert statement

Comment: Thank you all. I'm looking again at the OPENXML parameters and syntax to verify what I'm doing there.  Thank you all for your help and time.  Regards.

Comment: This is what I found, in the EXEC statement I forgot to add the @fromToMach variable that I was supposed to be passing in when I executed the SP.  When I re-ran this SP I then received an error stating: Msg 257, Level 16, State 31, Procedure sp_xml_preparedocument, Line 1
Implicit conversion from data type bit to ntext is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

@fromToMatch shouldn't be supplied as the last parameter of the sp_xml_preparedocument stored procedure.

That param is for an xPath Namespace, which you do not appear to have any of in your sample XML, so there is no value required for this parameter in this situation.

Also, XML is CASE SensiTive, so in your OPENXML, change "Mach" to "MACH".

Without having the DDL for any of the tables involved, I can't accurately simulate it on my system, but give this a try:

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument 
    @idoc OUTPUT, 
    @xmlString;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages]
    --(really should list columns here)
SELECT 
    --really should list columns here
    --instead of 
    *
FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/MACH', 2) 
    WITH [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages];

SET @lastId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument 
   @idoc;   --never a bad idea to clean up!

UPDATE [dbo].[tblArchivedMessages] SET
    FromToMach = @fromToMach 
WHERE 
    ID = @lastId;
```

Give'er a try, see if it works. 
If not, script your "tblArchivedMessages" table, and post the DDL.

We'll get it working, one way or the other!

Cheers!

(Incidentally, this code DOES appear to work as is on my machine):

```
DECLARE 
    @idoc int, 
    @lastId int, 
    @xmlString varchar(max),
    @fromToMach bit


SET @xmlString = 
   '<MACH><B000>StringVal</B000><B002>StringVal</B002><B003>StringVal</B003><B004>StringVal</B004><B007>StringVal</B007><B011>StringVal</B011><B012>StringVal</B012><B013>StringVal</B013><B015>StringVal</B015><B018>StringVal</B018><B028>StringVal</B028><B032>StringVal</B032><B037>StringVal</B037><B039>StringVal</B039><B041>StringVal</B041><B043>StringVal</B043><B048>StringVal</B048><B049>StringVal</B049><B058>StringVal</B058><B061>StringVal</B061><B063>StringVal</B063><B127>StringVal</B127></MACH>';

SET @fromToMach = 1;

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument 
    @idoc OUTPUT, 
    @xmlString;


SELECT 
    --really should list columns here
    --instead of 
    *
FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/MACH', 2) 
        WITH
            (
                B000 VARCHAR(100),
                B001 VARCHAR(100), 
                B002 VARCHAR(100), 
                B003 VARCHAR(100), 
                B004 VARCHAR(100), 
                B005 VARCHAR(100), 
                B006 VARCHAR(100), 
                B007 VARCHAR(100), 
                B008 VARCHAR(100), 
                B009 VARCHAR(100), 
                B010 VARCHAR(100), 
                B011 VARCHAR(100), 
                B012 VARCHAR(100), 
                B013 VARCHAR(100), 
                B014 VARCHAR(100), 
                B015 VARCHAR(100), 
                B016 VARCHAR(100), 
                B017 VARCHAR(100), 
                B018 VARCHAR(100), 
                B019 VARCHAR(100), 
                B020 VARCHAR(100), 
                B021 VARCHAR(100), 
                B022 VARCHAR(100), 
                B023 VARCHAR(100), 
                B024 VARCHAR(100), 
                B025 VARCHAR(100), 
                B026 VARCHAR(100), 
                B027 VARCHAR(100), 
                B028 VARCHAR(100), 
                B029 VARCHAR(100), 
                B030 VARCHAR(100), 
                B031 VARCHAR(100), 
                B032 VARCHAR(100), 
                B033 VARCHAR(100), 
                B034 VARCHAR(100), 
                B035 VARCHAR(100), 
                B036 VARCHAR(100), 
                B037 VARCHAR(100), 
                B038 VARCHAR(100), 
                B039 VARCHAR(100), 
                B040 VARCHAR(100), 
                B041 VARCHAR(100), 
                B042 VARCHAR(100), 
                B043 VARCHAR(100), 
                B044 VARCHAR(100), 
                B045 VARCHAR(100), 
                B046 VARCHAR(100), 
                B047 VARCHAR(100), 
                B048 VARCHAR(100), 
                B049 VARCHAR(100), 
                B050 VARCHAR(100), 
                B051 VARCHAR(100), 
                B052 VARCHAR(100), 
                B053 VARCHAR(100), 
                B054 VARCHAR(100), 
                B055 VARCHAR(100), 
                B056 VARCHAR(100), 
                B057 VARCHAR(100), 
                B058 VARCHAR(100), 
                B059 VARCHAR(100), 
                B060 VARCHAR(100), 
                B061 VARCHAR(100), 
                B062 VARCHAR(100), 
                B063 VARCHAR(100), 
                B064 VARCHAR(100), 
                B065 VARCHAR(100), 
                B066 VARCHAR(100), 
                B067 VARCHAR(100), 
                B068 VARCHAR(100), 
                B069 VARCHAR(100), 
                B070 VARCHAR(100), 
                B071 VARCHAR(100), 
                B072 VARCHAR(100), 
                B073 VARCHAR(100), 
                B074 VARCHAR(100), 
                B075 VARCHAR(100), 
                B076 VARCHAR(100), 
                B077 VARCHAR(100), 
                B078 VARCHAR(100), 
                B079 VARCHAR(100), 
                B080 VARCHAR(100), 
                B081 VARCHAR(100), 
                B082 VARCHAR(100), 
                B083 VARCHAR(100), 
                B084 VARCHAR(100), 
                B085 VARCHAR(100), 
                B086 VARCHAR(100), 
                B087 VARCHAR(100), 
                B088 VARCHAR(100), 
                B089 VARCHAR(100), 
                B090 VARCHAR(100), 
                B091 VARCHAR(100), 
                B092 VARCHAR(100), 
                B093 VARCHAR(100), 
                B094 VARCHAR(100), 
                B095 VARCHAR(100), 
                B096 VARCHAR(100), 
                B097 VARCHAR(100), 
                B098 VARCHAR(100), 
                B099 VARCHAR(100), 
                B100 VARCHAR(100), 
                B101 VARCHAR(100), 
                B102 VARCHAR(100), 
                B103 VARCHAR(100), 
                B104 VARCHAR(100), 
                B105 VARCHAR(100), 
                B106 VARCHAR(100), 
                B107 VARCHAR(100), 
                B108 VARCHAR(100), 
                B109 VARCHAR(100), 
                B110 VARCHAR(100), 
                B111 VARCHAR(100), 
                B112 VARCHAR(100), 
                B113 VARCHAR(100), 
                B114 VARCHAR(100), 
                B115 VARCHAR(100), 
                B116 VARCHAR(100), 
                B117 VARCHAR(100), 
                B118 VARCHAR(100), 
                B119 VARCHAR(100), 
                B120 VARCHAR(100), 
                B121 VARCHAR(100), 
                B122 VARCHAR(100), 
                B123 VARCHAR(100), 
                B124 VARCHAR(100), 
                B125 VARCHAR(100), 
                B126 VARCHAR(100), 
                B127 VARCHAR(100)
            ) 


SET @lastId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument 
   @idoc;   --never a bad idea to clean up!
```