# SQL - Transactions Get Auto Increment Value Inside The Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqltransaction

I have 2 tables, the first table contains the minor details on the item and the second table contains the rest of the information.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO Items (Name, CategoryId) 
VALUES ('My Tv', 5);

INSERT INTO CharsToItem (ItemId, Value) 
VALUES ((SELECT Id FROM Items WHERE Id = @@Identity;), '65 Inch');

INSERT INTO CharsToItem (ItemId, Value) 
VALUES ((SELECT Id FROM Items WHERE Id = @@Identity;), '3840x2160');

COMMIT;
```

At the first insert to the `CharToItem` table, everything works perfectly, at the second time it says the return value is NULL and I can't insert it to the database.

Is there a way to save the Id in the select and use it several times?

Comment: For an explicit retrieval of identity or any computed value, use the OUTPUT clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first insert into the `CharsToItem` table, `@@Identity` returns the id of newly inserted item in `CharsToItem`.

Therefore, after inserting into `Items`, store the id in a variable

```
DECLARE @itemId int -- Variable to store the last ItemId.

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO Items (Name, CategoryId) VALUES ('My Tv', 5);
SET @itemId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();  -- Store the new ItemId

INSERT INTO CharsToItem (ItemId, Value) VALUES (@itemId, '65 Inch');
INSERT INTO CharsToItem (ItemId, Value) VALUES (@itemId, '3840x2160');

COMMIT;
```

Note that you don't have to SELECT the last id from something, `@@IDENTITY` or `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` return this last id already.

Note also that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is safer than `@@IDENTITY`, as `@@IDENTITY` could return an id created by a trigger, for instance.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/567186/880990) to this SO question: [scope_identity vs ident_current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567171/scope-identity-vs-ident-current).

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @ItemId int;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO Items (Name, CategoryId) VALUES ('My Tv', 5);

SET @ItemId = scope_identity();

INSERT INTO CharsToItem (ItemId, Value) VALUES (@ItemId, '65 Inch');
INSERT INTO CharsToItem (ItemId, Value) VALUES (@ItemId, '3840x2160');

COMMIT;
```